# SQL create age range from birth date values

Tags: sql, date, grouping

i want to create a column AGEGROUP with the age ranges:
'under 30'
'30 - 40'
'40 - 50'
'50 - 60'
'60 - 70'
'over 70'
with the values of the current date -BIRTH_DATE from table XSALES.CUSTOMERS

Itried this but output shows:
"FROM keyword not found where expected"

```
select *,
  case
    when datediff(now(), BIRTH_DATE) / 365.25 < 30 then 'under 30'
    when datediff(now(), BIRTH_DATE) / 365.25 < 41 then '30 - 40'
    when datediff(now(), BIRTH_DATE) / 365.25 < 51 then '40 - 50'
    when datediff(now(), BIRTH_DATE) / 365.25 < 61 then '50 - 60'
    when datediff(now(), BIRTH_DATE) / 365.25 < 71 then '60 - 70'
    else 'over 70'
  end as AGEGROUP
from XSALES.CUSTOMERS;
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I am using the xsales database that has already existing tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```sql
select *, AGEGROUP =
  case
    when datediff(Day, BIRTH_DATE, GetDate()) / 365.25 < 30 then 'under 30'
    when datediff(Day, BIRTH_DATE, GetDate()) / 365.25 < 41 then '30 - 40'
    when datediff(Day, BIRTH_DATE, GetDate()) / 365.25 < 51 then '40 - 50'
    when datediff(Day, BIRTH_DATE, GetDate()) / 365.25 < 61 then '50 - 60'
    when datediff(Day, BIRTH_DATE, GetDate()) / 365.25 < 71 then '60 - 70'
    else 'over 70'
  end 
from XSALES.CUSTOMERS;
```

Comment: it still has the same result

Comment: Sorry, never heard about _xsales_ ... do you have a link to some documentation, please?